# Extracting text between tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract text from a series of webpages that all follow a similar format using BeautifulSoup. The html for the text I wish to extract is below. The actual link is here: http://www.p2016.org/ads1/bushad120215.html.

```
 <p><span style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"></span><font size="-1">      <span
 style="font-family: Arial;"><big><span style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"></span></big></span></font><span style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"></span><font size="-1"><span style="font-family: Arial;"><big><span
 style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"></span></big></span></font><font
 size="-1"><span style="font-family: Arial;"><big><span style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"></span></big></span></font><font size="-1"><span style="font-family: Arial;"><big><span style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);"></span></big></span></font></p>   <p><span style="color: rgb(153, 153, 153);">[Music]</span><span
 style="text-decoration: underline;"><br>
</span></p>
<p><small><span style="text-decoration: underline;">TEXT</span>: The
Medal of Honor is the highest award for valor in action against an
enemy force</small><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><br>
</span></p>
<p><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Col. Jay Vargas</span>:&nbsp;
We
were
completely
surrounded,
116 Marines locking heads with 15,000
North Vietnamese.&nbsp; Forty hours with no sleep, fighting hand to
hand.<span style="text-decoration: underline;"><br>
<span style="font-family: helvetica,sans-serif;"><br>
</span>
```

I'd like to find a way to iterate through all the html files in my folder and extract the text between all the markers. I've included here the relevant sections of my code:

```
text=[]

for page in pages:
        html_doc = codecs.open(page, 'r')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
        for t in soup.find_all('<p>'):
            t = t.get_text()
            text.append(t.encode('utf-8'))
            print t
```

However, nothing is coming up. Apologies for the noob question and thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

> `for t in soup.find_all('<p>'):`

Just specify the *tag name*, not it's representation:

```
for t in soup.find_all('p'):
```

---

Here is how you can narrow down the search to the dialogue paragraphs:

```
for span in soup.find_all("span", style="text-decoration: underline;"):
    text = span.next_sibling

    if text:
        print(span.text, text.strip())
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that there are other <p>'s before this block and I wanted to select just this one. I'm not sure if there are the same number of <p>'s in each file...

Comment: @StanO not a problem, I had a feeling you'd want to narrow down your search. It is just a bit unclear which `p` elements do you want to extract and what differs them from others? Thanks!

Comment: That obvious, huh? :-) I put the link to the actual html above. Maybe there is something that I missed, but I think the span objects are the most distinguishing features.

Comment: @StanO okay, let's think about it differently: for the provided link, what would be your desired output?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like the dialogue of the commercial in one list and the "Notes:" section in another. I've been trying to do that with regex, but with little luck...

Comment: @StanO updated, this should put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks much for this lead @alecxe! However, it's still throwing me an error for pages that look like this: http://www.p2016.org/ads1/christiead100515.html. Any pointers?