# Extracting texts after <br> with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a series of web pages I want to scrape text from that all follow different patterns unfortunately. I'm trying to write a scraper that extracts text after `<br>` tags, as that structure is common to all pages.

The pages follow three basic patterns as best I can tell:

1. http://www.p2016.org/ads1/bushad120215.html
2. http://www.p2016.org/ads1/christiead100515.html
3. http://www.p2016.org/ads1/patakiad041615.html

As I have it now, I'm scraping with the following loop:

```
  for br in soup.find_all('br'):
        text = br.next_sibling

        try:         
            print text.strip().replace("\t", " ").replace("\r", " ").replace('\n', ' ')
        except AttributeError:
            print('...')
```

While this script works for some pages, but only grabs some or none of the text for other ones. I've been tearing my hair out on this for the last few days, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I tried [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34388284/extracting-text-between-tags-using-beautifulsoup) already, but couldn't make it work for all the pages.

Comment: There isn't really a "between" for <br> tags since there is no open & close. I think you just mean "after", right?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would still continue relying on the `underline` style of the span elements. Here is a sample code that should help you get started (using [`.next_siblings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings)):

```
for span in soup.select('p > span[style*=underline]'):
    texts = []
    for sibling in span.next_siblings:
        # break upon reaching the next span 
        if sibling.name == "span":
            break

        text = sibling.get_text(strip=True) if isinstance(sibling, Tag) else sibling.strip()
        if text:
            texts.append(text.replace("\n", " "))

    if texts:
        text = " ".join(texts)
        print(span.text.strip(), text.strip())
```

Comment: The more I mess with this, the more it seems you're right. The output I'm getting is multiple strings, not just one that would fit into the csv cell. Do I have my output script wrong? 
`with open('p2016ads.csv', 'wb') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar="|")
    writer.writerow(["group", "text", "details","link"])
    rows = zip(org,txt,deets, link)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)`